# How to get the context with RouterContext using in v6.22?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, code-migration

I am new to React development and was assigned with task of upgrading to the latest libraries. Looking at the existing code seems to be written generically to meet any react project using react-router v5.

I am looking at a code solution using react-router v6 in the routing part that is given

code in react-client.js

```
import { hydrate as render, renderRoutes } from '@mna/react'
import createStore from '@mna/store'
import connectReduxDevTools from '@mna/store/redux'

// From react-server/render
const initState = window.__INIT_STATE__
const splitPoints = window.__SPLIT_POINTS__ || []

const siteName = window.location.hostname

export default function renderClient({ App, routes, bundles = {} }) {

  const store = createStore(App)

  if (initState) store.setState(initState, { silent: true })

  connectReduxDevTools(store)

  const el = document.getElementById('root')
  const renderApp = () => render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      { renderRoutes(routes, { store, siteName }) }
    </BrowserRouter>,
    el
  )

  store.on('setState', renderApp)

  return Promise.all(
    splitPoints.map(chunk => bundles[chunk] ? bundles[chunk].loadComponent() : (
      console.warn('Route chunk not found', { chunk, bundles }) && Promise.resolve()
    ))
  ).then(renderApp)
}
```

renderRoutes.js

```
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import Switch from './Switch'

const renderRoutes = (routes, routeProps = {}, switchProps = {}) =>{
  return routes ? (
    <Switch {...switchProps}>
      { routes.map((route, i) => (
        <Route
          key={route.key || i}
          path={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          strict={route.strict}
          render={props =>
            route.render
              ? route.render({ ...props, ...routeProps, route })
              : <route.component {...props} {...routeProps} route={route} />
          }
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  ) : null
}

export default renderRoutes
```

switch.js

```
import { __RouterContext as RouterContext, matchPath } from "react-router"

/**
 * The public API for rendering the first <Route> that matches.
 */
export default class Switch extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RouterContext.Consumer>
        {context => {

          const location = this.props.location || context.location

          let element, match

          // We use React.Children.forEach instead of React.Children.toArray().find()
          // here because toArray adds keys to all child elements and we do not want
          // to trigger an unmount/remount for two <Route>s that render the same
          // component at different URLs.
          React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
            if (match == null && React.isValidElement(child)) {
              element = child

              const path = child.props.path || child.props.from

              match = path
                ? matchPath(location.pathname, { ...child.props, path })
                : context.match
            }
          })

          return match
            ? React.cloneElement(element, { location, computedMatch: match })
            : null
        }}
      </RouterContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

how can I achieve same kind of functionality keeping it generic. Please let me know if you need any further details related to the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The existing/old code seems needlessly convoluted.... I see no reason why any React Context was ever so heavily coupled to router/routing logic. ‍♂️ Just create the `RouterContext` as per usual, and components that need to consume it should use the `useContext` hook. Instead of copying forward poor/impractical designs perhaps this is a great opportunity to re-assess the use case(s) and any associated business rules and write cleaner code. Can you [edit] to clarify what the existing code is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, Thank you for the response.  As I mentioned, I am not done much of work on React, but since it is assigned to me as task, I trying to understand and achieve the functionality.

Comment: React-Router 6 did away with all the route props, we use React hooks to access the path `location` and `params` objects. What does this `RouterContext` in that code do? What context value is it providing? If you understand what the purpose of the `RouterContext` and this `Switch` component are and can clearly explain their use case then we might be able to inform on a RRDv6 version.

Comment: As per the code flow, my understanding is that each of the route it is going to generate is doing a match path check and then generate the route element.  And with the old version RouterContext code that I referenced it is dynamically generating the context and is returned back with the path. Hope, my understanding is in right path, if not please correct and provide me the code solution that replaces this reusable approach.  It is bit difficult for me to write such code in the given timeline in the project.
Hoping for a helpful response.

Comment: React-Router, and specifically the `Routes` component in v6, handles the route matching, there's no point really in re-inventing that wheel. From what I can tell, you just need to map an array of `RouteObject` objects to `Route` components inside a `Routes` (*RRDv6 replacement of the v5 `Switch` component*), and for any components that need to access the provided `RouterContext` they would use the `useContext` hook, e.g. something like `const routeContext = useContext(RouterContext);`. I can't tell what any of the "v5" code does really beyond this.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, Thank you for the functional clarification.  Can you please share a good example that gives a generic way of writing the new way of implementation, so that I can go thru and try it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean as an answer? Sure, I don't mind. Can you [edit] to include an example of the `routes` array that is passed to `renderClient`, and what `App` and `createStore` do?

Comment: Here is how the project is structured.
There are around 30 - 40 pages that are routed based on the functional logic.
Starting with App route path to each navigating link this common code is called upon and route is built dynamically.  There is client.js file that calls react-client.js passing App, routes, bundles as parameters.